# jQuery/jQuery Mobile .data() attaching data that cannot be retrieved in click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in a loop:

```
            newLink = "<li class=\"styledli\" id=\"id" + i + "\" ><p>" + list[i] + "</p></li>";
            htmlListString = htmlListString + newLink;

    $("#id"+i).data("parm1",list[i]);
```

Outside the loop I do:

```
    $('#listUL').empty();

$('#listUL').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
        alert("Works id="+this.id); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    console.log("this.id="+this.id+" parm1="+JSON.stringify($("#"+this.id).data()));
    });

$('#listUL').append(htmlListString);
```

When this runs the alert shows the proper id but console.log shows "parm1={}"

I don't understand why.  I moved  `$('#listUL').empty();` before the loop ran and that had no effect.  I moved `$('#listUL').on('click',` after  `$('#listUL').append(htmlListString);` as well and that had no effect.

How you do you used `.data()` to attach data items to and element and THEN how do you retrieve them in a click function?

Comment: Have you tried `.attr("data-parm1")` instead of `.data("parm1")`?  Sometimes the latter doesn't work when the first does.

Comment: Also is there a reason you're storing an entire json object in one data attribute?

Comment: $("#"+this.id).attr("data-parm1") returns "undefined".  i've been so focused on trying to figure out what's wrong that I overlooked it makes more sense to break the JSON up than pass it whole.

Comment: i tried this $("#id"+i).data() immediately after i did $("#id"+i).data("parm1",list[i]); and IT returned undefined.  how on earth do you use .data()?

Comment: All the `.data()` method does is add a data attribute to the html element. Example: `<div data-myValue="1">` is the same as `.data("myValue",1)`.  But sometimes using `.attr()` works when `.data()` doesn't, it's weird.  I normally just use `.attr("data-...")` instead of `.data()` anyhow.  It has its uses, but not sure if what you're trying to use it for is something I would do.Look at the docs for more info.

Comment: is list[i] just a string, or is it an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use .data() on the listitem before you have actually added it to the DOM.  The selector `$("#id"+i)` will return zero items until after the line `$('#listUL').append(htmlListString);`

In your situation, the easiest thing to do is include the data attribute in the listitem string:

```
var newLink = "<li data-parm1=\"" + list[i] + "\" class=\"styledli\" id=\"id" + i + "\" ><p>" + list[i] + "</p></li>";
```

Also, if you just want to return the plain string of param1, you do not need the JSON.stringify(), instead: `$(this).data("parm1")`

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sqz5fmsr/2/)**

Comment: can data-parm1 be anything other than a string?

Comment: interesting.  an Array works fine.  an Array with strings at the indexes is displayed at "" in the click handler.  an Object appears as [Object object] in the click handler.  do you know what i'm missing?

Comment: wait.  does this automagically convert everything to a string somehow?

Comment: @user1126515, here is the fiddle updated with some different data types: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sqz5fmsr/4/ . Ultimately the values are stored in the browser as strings.